# Why is my flexbox set container not breaking correctly?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a block of cards which are arranged within a container like so:

```
<div class="projekt_wrapper">
    <div class="projekt_card">
        <div class="projekt_breadcrumb"><span>Headline</span><span>The title</span></div>
        <div class="projekt_container">
            <h1>Title again - for you</h1>
            <p>Caption for the image</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="projekt_card">
        <div class="projekt_breadcrumb"><span>Headline</span><span>The title</span></div>
        <div class="projekt_container">
            <h1>Title again - for you</h1>
            <p>Caption for the image</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="projekt_card">
        <div class="projekt_breadcrumb"><span>Headline</span><span>The title</span></div>
        <div class="projekt_container">
            <h1>Title again - for you</h1>
            <p>Caption for the image</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want/do arrange these cards with flexbox like so:

```
.projekt_wrapper{
  width:91.68vw;
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 200vh;
  max-height: 8000px;
  font-size: 0;  
}

.projekt_card{
    width:50%;
    margin:0;
}
.projekt_card *{
    max-width:100%;
}

.projekt_container{
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1207766/projekte-digitalready.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    min-height:100vh;
    padding-top:20vh;
}


.projekt_container h1, .projekt_container p{
    color:red;
    text-align:center;
    max-width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 2vh;
}

.projekt_container p{
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
    padding-bottom:5vh;
}


.projekt_container img{
    margin:8vh 48%;
    max-width:4vw;
}
```

You may also have a look at it right here: http://codepen.io/daiaiai/pen/mRGdaR

And there you'll see the problem that I have by them inner-blocks not breaking into a new line correctly.  What do I need to do to make it work correctly?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's unclear what "them inner-blocks not breaking into a new line correctly" means. they're breaking as your CSS is defined to break. this what you're trying to do? http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/PWdorK

Comment: Sorry for being unclear there. No, I actually wanted to have a width of 50% of each child element and afterwards the new line shall start. So 2 items of .projekt_card per line
// See here: 
.projekt_card{
    width:50%;
    margin:0;
}

Comment: remove `flex-direction: column;` if you want 2 per row.

Comment: thanks! What would be the correct approach: Adding flex-direction: row; or leaving that property completely empty?

Comment: Either, they're the same thing.